# How do I setup model for table object with arrays of responses in sequelize

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am having challenge on how to setup model for table object with arrays of responses in Sequelize ORM. I use Postgres DB. I have a table say foo. Foo has columns

```
A

B

C
> C1_SN

  C1_Name

  C1_Address

  C1_Phone

D

E
```

The column C has a boolean question, if the user select true, he will need to provide array of responses for C1. Such as we now have:

```
  C1_SN1

  C1_Name1

  C1_Address1

  C1_Phone1
------
  C1_SN2

  C1_Name2

  C1_Address2

  C1_Phone2
-----
  C1_SN3

  C1_Name3

  C1_Address3

  C1_Phone3
```

I expect multiple teams to be filling this table. How do I setup the model in sequelize? I have two options in mind.

**Option 1**

The first option I think of is to create an extra 1:1 table between Foo and C1. But going with this option, I don't know how to bulkCreate the array of C1 responses in the C1 table.

**Option 2**

I think it's also possible to make C1 column in Foo table have a nested array of values. Such that if userA submit his data, it will have the nested array of C1. But I don't know how to go about this method as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create separate table for C if user select true then need pass array of object and then pass in bulkCreate like.

C1_SN AutoIncrement
 
C1_NAME
C1_Address
C1_Phone

value=[{"C1_NAME":"HELLo","C1_Address":"HELLo","C1_Phone":"987456321"},{"C1_NAME":"HELLo1","C1_Address1":"HELLo","C1_Phone":"987456321s"}]

```html
foo.bulkCreate(value).then(result=>{
console.log(result)
}).catch(error=>{
console.log(error)
})
```

From the official you can check this link:
[Sequelize bulkCreate](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-bulkCreate)

Comment: Thanks @aum I finally sorted it out by creating extra table and using transaction.